# Como armazeno vários valores em cada "option" de um "select"?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Eu tenho uma *option* e dois *inputs* para alimentar de acordo com o resultado do *select*.

No *select* é escolhido o usuário e nos dois *inputs* são inseridos o endereço e o email do usuário selecionado.

Eu gostaria de saber se é possível ter 2 *values* possíveis para alimentar os *inputs*.

Meu código atual é esse, o select já funciona, mas não sei como inserir o segundo valor:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('change', '.get-placa', function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $('.close').trigger('click');
        $('.nome').val(value);
        $('.email').val("aqui seria outro value");
    });
</script>
    <div class="control-group col1">
        <label class="control-label">Paciente</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <select class="form-control get-placa chzn-select" type="text"  name="patient_id">
                <option value="">select</option>
                <option value="rua um">Maria</option>
                <option value="avenida dois">Jose</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group col1">
        <label class="control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('endereço');?></label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input  readonly="true" type="text" class="form-control nome" name="nome">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control-group col1">
        <label class="control-label"><?php echo get_phrase('email');?></label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input  readonly="true" type="text" class="form-control email" name="email">
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Armazenando dados arbitrários em uma *tag*

Usando `data-attributes` podemos colocar dados arbitrários em praticamente qualquer tag HTML. No nosso caso, podemos por vários valores no `option` desta maneira:

```
<option
   value="Rua Um"
   data-id="101"
   data-email="jose@example.com"
   data-tiposanguineo="O+"
>José</option>
<!-- sempre usando data-nomedoatributo para cada ítem -->
```

### O `value` é do `select`, mas queremos os dados do `option`

Você atualmente pega o `value` com `.val`. Este valor não vem do `option`, pois o `this` se refere ao `select` que mudou e, consequentemente o `.val` vem do `value` atualizado pela seleção do usuário. Ocorre que nós precisamos recuperar os `data-attributes` que ficam lá no `option` e não diretamente no `select`.

Só que quando a opção selecionada muda, não é só o `value` que sofre uma alteração. O `option` correspondente ganha o atributo `:selected`, então podemos nos referir a ele desta forma:

```
var option = $(this).find("option:selected");
```

Agora que já aprendemos a localizar o `option` selecionado, basta recuperar os `data-attributes` que nos interessam. Com jQuery 1.4.3 ou maior, basta usar o `.data()`:

```
var email = option.data('email'); // recuperamos o data-email
var id    = option.data('id');    // e o data-id ...
// ... e quantos outros .data() necessitarmos
```

### E se precisarmos do conteúdo textual da *tag* `option`?

Não é o seu caso, mas em algumas situações, queremos também o texto dentro da tag `option`. Usando a mesma lógica do `find` acima, podemos obter este com o `text`, evitando um `data-attribute` redundante:

```
var option = $(this).find("option:selected");
var nome = option.text();
```

## Demonstração:

Juntando as etapas anteriores, vamos a uma breve demonstração.

Note que simplifiquei o código para nos atermos aos pontos que realmente importam. Entendendo o funcionamento, fica fácil adaptar ao seu *layout* original.

### Usando JS puro:

```html
<label class="control-label">Paciente</label><br>
<select type="text" id="meuselect">
   <option value="">select</option>
   <option value="Rua Um"   data-id="101" data-email="jose@example.com">José</option>
   <option value="Rua Dois" data-id="122" data-email="maria@gmail.moc">Maria</option>
   <option value="Rua Três" data-id="134" data-email="zuul@gmail.noexist">Le Zuul</option>
</select><br>

<label>id</label><br>
<input id="id" readonly="true" type="text" name="id"><br>

<label>endereco</label><br>
<input id="endereco" readonly="true" type="text" name="endereco"><br>

<label>email</label><br>
<input id="email" readonly="true" type="text" name="email"><br>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var sel = document.getElementById('meuselect');
   sel.onchange = function () {
      var value  = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value; // aqui pode sel.value
      var id     = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-id');
      var email  = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-email');

      document.getElementById('id'      ).value = id;
      document.getElementById('endereco').value = value;
      document.getElementById('email'   ).value = email;
   };
</script>
```

Ainda, há uma maneira mais específica de pegar `data-attributes` (a do exemplo acima é para atributos em geral), como exemplificado pelo colega Diogo nos comments, usando o membro `dataset` (verifique a tabela de compatibilidade). Segue link:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Modo de usar:

```
 <div data-girafa="sim">
 ...
 console.log(elemento.dataset.girafa); // sem o prefixo data-
```

### Usando jQuery, como na pergunta:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).on('change', '#meuselect', function () {
      var value  = $(this).val();
      var option = $(this).find("option:selected");

      var id    = option.data('id');
      var email = option.data('email');

      $('#endereco').val(value);
      $('#email'   ).val(email);
      $('#id'      ).val(id);
   });
</script>

<label class="control-label">Paciente</label><br>
<select type="text" id="meuselect">
   <option value="">select</option>
   <option value="Rua Um"   data-id="101" data-email="jose@example.com">José</option>
   <option value="Rua Dois" data-id="122" data-email="maria@gmail.moc">Maria</option>
   <option value="Rua Três" data-id="134" data-email="zuul@gmail.noexist">Le Zuul</option>
</select><br>

<label>id</label><br>
<input id="id" readonly="true" type="text" name="id"><br>

<label>endereco</label><br>
<input id="endereco" readonly="true" type="text" name="endereco"><br>

<label>email</label><br>
<input id="email" readonly="true" type="text" name="email"><br>
```

### Nota:

Não precisa disso para funcionar, mas o ideal é que os seletores dos campos não sejam ambíguos. Para o demo acima, trocamos as classes por IDs, ficando assim:

```
$('#email').val(email);
```

E nos `inputs`, acrescentamos o ID correspondente:

```
<input id="email" ...
```

Comment: Muito obrigada! Era exatamente isso que não sabia como fazer. Valeu!!

Comment: É possível acessar atributos customizáveis sem ser por jQuery, só com JavaScript puro (document.getElem...)?

Comment: @Diogo depois de obter o elemento, faça `elemento.getAttribute('data-nomedoatributo');` - e se quiser usar com CSS puro também dá em alguns casos: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/163527/70

Comment: @Diogo atualizei a resposta com uma versão sem jquery

Comment: @Bacco muito obrigado. Depois de ter feito essa pergunta eu até que fucei um pouco aqui e consegui obter esses values através dessa forma (vou seguir um de seus exemplos): `elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].dataset.email`. Assim também deu certinho. Será que são similares ou pode haver alguma diferença (entre essa forma que descrevi e a da sua resposta)?

Comment: @Diogo vai muito da compatibilidade esperada, sempre bom ver no https://caniuse.com - eu geralmente, para fins de Stack Overflow procuro fazer mais didático (onde não compromete o resultado) até pra ser reaproveitado de outras formas (por exemplo, se não fosse usado data-attributes, mas fosse pegar alguma outra característica). - Na MDN já tem a tabela de compatibilidaade do dataset também, segue link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset  - Complementei a resposta com sua sugestão.